# How to read exit code of powershell script from C# code

Tags: c#, powershell

I want to execute following power shell script from C# code

```
Add-Content D:\f.txt "Import Module"
Add-Content D:\f.txt "Remove Module"
Add-Content D:\f.txt "The End"
exit 4
```

I can execute the script from the C# code successfully.

I want my C# program to read the exit value (i.e. 4) returned from the powershell.

Can you please let me know how I can achieve it?
Note: I am new to C# and powershell.

Comment: Please show us the C# code how you execute the script. The Powershell code itself is not much of interest for answering your question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to read PowerShell exit code via c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12895503/how-to-read-powershell-exit-code-via-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

same probleam as [How to read PowerShell exit code via c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12895503/how-to-read-powershell-exit-code-via-c-sharp), it seems that you need to try alternative approach like PowerShell.Streams.Error or Runspace.RunspaceStateInfo rather than exit code.